# How much time an iOS app is guaranteed to stay in the background without being removed from the memory?

Tags: ios, memory-management, background, viewcontroller

I have a Swift iOS app consisting of 3 view controllers – the initial one with a tableview, the second one with the chosen element and ability to create a new time session and the third one with the actual timer for the session (let’s call it the timer vc).

In this case, the focus is the timer view controller. However, the question is not about the timer itself. It works both in foreground and background mode. The problem is this:

The app goes background. Then over a certain fixed period of time, it receives a local notification – a reminder to go back to the timer vc and save the results. Most of the time, it works fine but sometimes when you go back to the app (through notification), it opens the initial vc with the tableview instead of the timer vc, which seems like the system terminates the background app after a while and then reopens it when you go back through the notification. In this case, all the data from the timer vc are obviously lost since the app logic requires that the user save the data after the session is finished.

What I think, the essence of the problem may have to do with how long the app can stay in the background without being terminated or suspended (If I’m not mistaken, in this state, all the current data associated with the app are removed from the memory). I mean, when you set the notifications to be triggered like every 1, 5 or 10 minutes, everything seems to be fine. However, when the notification is set for 30 minutes or more, the mentioned bug seems to appear from time to time (especially when testing on an actual device instead of a simulator). For the most part, it appears if the device storage is almost full - under 1Gb of free space). Which leads me to believe that this may also be a memory management issue.

How to make this timer vc run in the background as much time as needed? Also, does anybody know how much time an iOS app is guaranteed to stay in the background without being removed from the memory? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no "guarantee", as it depends on several factors, including (a) the specific device and it's memory size, and (b) what other apps are competing for it's memory. The only "guarantee" is that the various `AppDelegate` methods *should* fire. (I say *should* because I'm sure that there are exceptions to that, like the user power's down the device.)

Answer (score 0):

**There is no guarantee of your's app execution time when it is in background mode.** The operating system can suspend it anytime, Operating system has the responsibility only to notify your app which you will receive in the app delegate.

For setting up the local notification, you need to get the help from OS only. You can't rely on your app's execution in the background thread. For scheduling and handling of local notifications, you can go through the following documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1